# Does Uint8Array use a shared memory buffer in Node and Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, arraybuffer

If I create a 2 byte Buffer, the underlying ArrayBuffer is 8 KB, sometimes. But if I create a 2 byte Uint8Array, is there any risk that the underlying ArrayBuffer will be any bigger or can I always rely on it to be 2 bytes.

The example code would be `new Uint8Array(2).buffer.byteLength`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can rely on `new Uint8Array( length )` to create an *ArrayBuffer* with *byteLength* `length`.

The steps we're interested in to create a `new Uint8Array( length )` are

- call [*TypedArray ( length )*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typedarray-length)
- call [*AllocateTypedArray*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-allocatetypedarray) ( `"Uint8Array"`, *NewTarget*, *%TypedArray.prototype%*, `length` ).
- call [*AllocateTypedArrayBuffer*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-allocatetypedarraybuffer) ( *obj*, `length` ).
- let `elementSize` be the *Element Size* value specified in [Table 63](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-the-typedarray-constructors) for "Uint8Array" => `1`
- let `byteLength` be `elementSize` × `length`.
- call [*AllocateArrayBuffer*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-allocatearraybuffer) ( *%ArrayBuffer%*, `byteLength` ).

Now, while this is true for `Uint8Array` it's not for all TypedArrays.

The important part here is my fourth bullet, where `elementSize` is determined from [this table](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-allocatearraybuffer) since this value will get used as a multiplier to the final `byteLength`  argument.

```js
test( Uint8Array ); // 2
test( Uint16Array ); // 4
test( Float64Array ); // 16

function test( constructor ) {
  console.log( constructor.name, new constructor( 2 ).buffer.byteLength );
}
```